# Concurrently run two functions that take parameters and return lists?

Tags: python, multithreading, list

I understand that two functions can run in parallel using `multiprocessing` or `threading` modules, e.g. [Make 2 functions run at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957116/make-2-functions-run-at-the-same-time) and [Python multiprocessing for parallel processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753306/python-multiprocessing-for-parallel-processes).

But the above examples only use print function. **Is it possible to run functions that return a list in parallel in python, if so, how?**

I've tried with threading:

```
from threading import Thread
def func1(x):
    return [i*i for i in x]

def func2(x):
    return [i*i*i for i in x]

nums = [1,2,3,4,5]

p1 = Thread(target = func1(nums)).start()
p2 = Thread(target = func2(nums)).start()

print p1
print p2
```

but i got the follow error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 761, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

None
None
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 761, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I've tried inputing `args` parameter as a tuple, instead of a variable:

```
import threading
from threading import Thread

def func1(x):
    return [i*i for i in x]

def func2(x):
    return [i*i*i for i in x]

nums = [1,2,3,4,5]

p1 = Thread(target = func1, args=(nums,)).start()
p2 = Thread(target = func2, args=(nums,)).start()

print p1, p2
```

but it only returns `None None`, the desired output should be:

**[out]:**

```
[1, 4, 9, 16, 25] [1, 8, 27, 64, 125]
```

Comment: `func1(nums)` evaluates before being passed to `Thread`, so you're effectively doing `p1 = Thread(target =[1,4,9,16,25]).start()`

Comment: Use `Thread(target=my_function, args=my_args)` so that the function is evaluated in the separate thread. Also `Thread.start()` returns `None`.

Comment: Once you get the threads running properly, this question may help you retrieve the results: [how to get the return value from a thread in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6893968/how-to-get-the-return-value-from-a-thread-in-python)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thread's target function cannot return a value. Or, I should say, the `return` value is ignored and as such, not communicated back to spawning thread. But here's a couple things you can do:

1. Communicate back to spawning thread using `queue.Queue`. Note the wrapper around the original functions:

   ```
    from threading import Thread
    from queue import Queue

    def func1(x):
        return [i*i for i in x]

    def func2(x):
        return [i*i*i for i in x]

    nums = [1,2,3,4,5]

    def wrapper(func, arg, queue):
        queue.put(func(arg))

    q1, q2 = Queue(), Queue()
    Thread(target=wrapper, args=(func1, nums, q1)).start() 
    Thread(target=wrapper, args=(func2, nums, q2)).start() 

    print(q1.get(), q2.get())
   ```
2. Use `global` to access result lists in your threads, as well as the spawning process:

   ```
    from threading import Thread

    list1, list2 = [], []

    def func1(x):
        global list1
        list1 = [i*i for i in x]

    def func2(x):
        global list2
        list2 = [i*i*i for i in x]

    nums = [1,2,3,4,5]

    Thread(target = func1, args=(nums,)).start()
    Thread(target = func2, args=(nums,)).start()

    print(list1, list2)
   ```

Comment: it returns `None None`.

Comment: Unfortunately the target function cannot communicate back to spawning thread using a `return`. One way to do it is to use a queue (I added such a solution to answer.)

Comment: Queue is queue in python so you have to `from queue import Queue`

Comment: Thanks @Skapis9999, I updated the code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Target should only receive the function name. The parameters should be passed with the parameter "args". I cannot paste the code because I am answering from my mobile phone... ;-)