# Execute two different functions at the same time in python 3.4.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multiprocessing

I have seen many examples about this topic but i cannot find any suitable answer for me.I need your help to know the trick about this.
Suppose, i have two function funA() and funB(). They take exactly same arguments. And the functions return two separate outputs i.e a pandas series object. I want to execute the functions at the same time without GIL. 
Here is my code sample:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from queue import Queue
q1 = Queue()
q2 = Queue()
res1 = Process(target=funA,args=(a,b,c,q1))
res1.start()
res2 = Process(target=funB,args=(a,b,c,q2))
res2.start()
res1.join()
res2.join()
result1 = q1.get()
result2 = q2.get()
```

The aforesaid code gives the following traceback:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 59, in dump
 ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '_thread.lock'>: attribute lookup lock on _thread failed
```

I have gone through the following threads like http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing_intro.html,
[Concurrently run two functions that take parameters and return lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22176780/concurrently-run-two-functions-that-take-parameters-and-return-lists), [Make 2 functions run at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957116/make-2-functions-run-at-the-same-time)

Please help me. Thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `multiprocessing.Queue` instead of `queue.Queue`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue

Comment: its giving the error:    `_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'module'>: attribute lookup module on builtins failed` @John

Comment: @sayak_SIBIA: please post a complete runnable program then, because I copied your code and added the necessary pieces and it worked for me on both Python 2 and Python 3.