# Python Multiprocessing - Parrallel processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm new to Python multiprocessing, and I'm trying to implement some parallel calculations. I've got the info that this:

```
#M is an integer, contains the number of processes I'd like to launch.
results = []
for i in range(0, M):
        p = Process(target=processchild, args=(data[i],q))
        p.start()
        result.append(q.get())
        p.join()
```

is still sequential, because `.join()` causes the loop to wait until `p` is finished before starting the next one. I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753306/python-multiprocessing-for-parallel-processes) in an answer, that

> You'll either want to join your processes individually outside of your for loop (e.g., by storing them in a list and then iterating over it)...

So if I'd modify my code to

```
results = []
for i in range(0, M):
        processes[i] = Process(target=processchild, args=(data[i],q))
        processes[i].start()
        result.append(q.get())

for i in range(0, M):
        processes[i].join()
```

Would it actually run in parallel now? If not, how can I modify my code to work that way? I've read the solution using `numpy.Pool` and `apply_async` posted as an answer to the question I previously linked, so I'm mostly interested in a solution that doesn't use these.

Comment: sounds correct. You should check with system tools that `M` processes are actually running concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will run in parallel.

All processes are started before you try joining one, so this will not block after the first process.

Comment: @robyschek Can I add `q.get()` to the second loop after the `join()`? Will that mean correct parallel running?

Comment: @robyschek Thank you!

Comment: @robyschek Since your answer was the correct one, I'll accept it if you add it as an answer! :)